# How to add a new group to an existing marathon application group hierarchy

Tags: mesos, marathon

After deploying a new marathon application group with a hierarchy something like below (note showing as yaml instead of json for readability) :

```
id: root_id
groups: 
- id: data_center_id
  groups:
  - id: category_id
    groups:
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
```

I now want to add an additional subgroup at the category level, so now it would look like this:

```
id: root_id
groups: 
- id: data_center_id
  groups:
  - id: category_id
    groups:
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
  # this is the new subgroup to add
  - id: category_id
    groups:
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
    - id: app_or_svc_type_id
      apps
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
      - id: app_id
        ....
```

When I attempt this via a PUT using the Marathon REST API, the existing group gets destroyed and the new subgroup gets created. Perhaps I'm missing something here but to add new micro-services for example, to an existing application group hierarchy, this functionality is critical.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you did exactly. Telling us about your exact HTTP requests might help.

Your problem might be that the IDs for your group and apps are not correct. Sometimes, this leads to ignored groups/apps without any error apparently: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/1890

The following HTTP requests work for me.

Create the initial group with one sub group:

```
PUT /v2/groups/group HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 185
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

{
    "groups": [
        {
            "apps": [
                {
                    "cmd": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer $PORT",
                    "id": "/group/subgroup1/app"
                }
            ],
            "id": "/group/subgroup1"
        }
    ],
    "id": "/group"
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Marathon-Leader: http://localhost:8080

{
    "deploymentId": "6c59b425-49e2-4db8-8de0-a29020a34be7",
    "version": "2015-07-28T12:00:01.171Z"
}
```

Update the group with a new definition containing an additional sub group:

```
PUT /v2/groups/group HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 335
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

{
    "groups": [
        {
            "apps": [
                {
                    "cmd": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer $PORT",
                    "id": "/group/subgroup1/app"
                }
            ],
            "id": "/group/subgroup1"
        },
        {
            "apps": [
                {
                    "cmd": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer $PORT",
                    "id": "/group/subgroup2/app"
                }
            ],
            "id": "/group/subgroup2"
        }
    ],
    "id": "/group"
}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Jetty(8.1.15.v20140411)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Marathon-Leader: http://localhost:8080

{
    "deploymentId": "b72801f7-8a18-434e-bebb-81d55e698ef1",
    "version": "2015-07-28T12:03:17.109Z"
}
```

The already existing applications/groups are left unchanged.

Alternatively, you could also use a `PUT` request to `/v2/groups/group/subgroup2` with only the definition of that sub group.

Comment: I'm going to test using the full id path on the update, that could be the issue. I'll post the results. Btw, what version of Marathon did you use? Also, my groups are more embedded than than your example. Could be an issue there but I'll confirm.

Comment: Just did some tests using the same json object as you posted above. The results are the same as before. If you POST a new group hierarchy and then attempt to update with an additional subgroup the original group will first get deleted and then the new one will get created. Because you added the second group to the original json, you don't see it being deleted. If you do the second group separately you should see your 1st subgroup disappear. Another way you can verify this is to go to the Mesos interface,filter on "KILLED" for completed tasks. Here you should see the original subgroup killed.

Comment: Again, I'm running Marathon 0.8.2. If you are running a newer version then maybe this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To add a subgroup, just `PUT` or `POST` the subgroup with its ID fully specified, in your case `/root_id/data_center_id/category_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael. To clarify, after I create the initial group structure. I do add the new path ending with the subgroup name. However, what occurs is the original group gets deleted and the group I wish to add get created as a new group. I do a PUT instead of POST because if you attempt to POST it will give a message that the group exists already, as expected.  I am running Marathon 0.8.2.

Comment: Just to be clear: from your app spec description above it looks like you PUT the entire group structure and I suggested to only do the diff. Can you clarify pls?

Comment: Sure. The json contains only the new subgroup objects. The url is pointed to the path of the new category being added. Nothing from the existing group objects are contained in the PUT. For example http://172.180.10.2/v2/groups/root_id/data_center_id/category_id, where category_id (note I'm aware that underscores aren't allowed in the id names - so it would be category-id) is the new one being added.